# Why is setting same height for multiple columns not working when resizing window?

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I have a function that sets the same height for the columns with text.

It works fine on desktop, but does nothing on resizing the window.

What can be a problem?

The code is below. Thanks.

```
function columnSize() {
    var maxheight = 0;
    $('.service .wrap .intro').each(function() {
        if($(this).innerHeight() > maxheight) { maxheight = $(this).innerHeight(); }
    });
    $('.service .wrap .intro').innerHeight(maxheight);      
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    columnSize();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    columnSize();
});
```

Comment: Can you create a simple example for this on http://jsfiddle.net the code looks fine

Comment: Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhboyzgx/1/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the height is set on the div when the page first loads. This sets a style attribute on the div so when you check the div for the height again, it simply pulls that value which is why it never changes. You need to reset the height to auto before setting them again

See here http://jsfiddle.net/rhboyzgx/2/

```
function columnSize() {
    var maxheight = 0;
    var $intros = $('.service .wrap .intro');
    $intros.css("height","auto");
    $intros.each(function() {
        var h = $(this).innerHeight();
        if( h > maxheight ) { 
            maxheight = h;
        }
    });
    $intros.innerHeight(maxheight);     
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    columnSize();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    columnSize();
});
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as correct